# readonly in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I make a textbox read only in mvc?  I have included the following snippet, but it`s not working.

```
 <%=Html.Textbox("test", "test", new { style="border: 0px; width:280px" ;readonly=true}%>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/177673/html-textbox-conditional-attribute-with-asp-net-mvc-preview-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%=Html.Textbox("test", "test", new { style="border: 0px; width:280px", @readonly =  "readonly"}%>
```